# How to set up dnsmasq on PC to mimic router's comfort functions?

Tags: dns, hostname, dnsmasq

I want to move the DNS functionality from my router to a PC running `dnsmasq` on the network. The basic setup is up and running, but I am missing the following functions the router had implemented:

- hostnames on the devices are automatically used, no `/etc/hosts` file maintenance necessary
- ability to address devices by their hostname, not only by IP
- assignment of `.local` domain to all the devices
- works with and without the .local domain, i.e. http://box1 and http://box1.local are both legal and can be used to browse the box1 server
- works with Windows, Android, Linux clients and others

DHCP is still running on the router; I have added a file `00-basic.conf` to `/etc/dnsmasq.d`:

```
domain=local
expand-hosts
local=/local/
address=/my.router/192.168.1.1
```

This addresses the first four bullet points, but not the fifth. It works with Windows clients, Ubuntu clients, but *not* Android and a Slackware system. Android gives `android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA` in a shell.

What do I need to do to get the functionality mentioned for all systems, like I had when the router was responsible for DNS? Why does it even happen?